# object to String modification in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, object

i got object like this.

```
Object {
  "company": "984",
  "id": "1",
}
```

i want to access **company** and **id** individually.

The result should look like this

```
"984"
"1"
```

How can i achieve these?Thanks.

Comment: hello!
I suggest you loop through the object to get the keys ("company" and "id" in this case) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries . 

Then you can use string manipulation to add/concat the "-->" to the key and value.

Comment: i want only "984"and "1".

Comment: out of interest, if you know you want `company` and `id` why are tyou not just reading them as `myObject.company` and `myObject.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will give you an array of the values

```js
const obj = {
  "company": "984",
  "id": "1",
};

console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

You can of course assign this array to a variable and then access the values individually

```
const vals = Object.values(obj);
console.log(vals[0]); /// "984"
console.log(vals[1]); /// "1"
```

Comment: i dont need array..only two value individually."984" "1"

Answer (score 1):

You can write the following function:

```js
let obj = {
  "company": "984",
  "id": "1",
}

let printObject = function(obj) {
    let props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
    props.forEach(el => {
        console.log('' + el + '--->', obj[el]);
    });
}

printObject(obj);
```

Comment: what is (o) here?

Comment: i got value in integer but i want like this: "984" and "1"